# How to report state changes on devices over real-time feed for Smart Home apps?

Tags: actions-on-google

[Documentation for `SYNC` intent](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app#actiondevicessync) mentions that if `willReportState` property of a device is `true`, the device will report its state through Real Time Feed.

How do I write state updates to the Real Time Feed? I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/report-state) to do it is available.

First you'll need to enable the HomeGraph API and obtain an API key. Then you should send a POST request to `https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/devices:reportStateAndNotification` with a JWT and the following payload:

```
{
 "requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf",
 "agent_user_id": "1234",
 "payload": {
    "devices": {
      "states": {
        "1458765": {
          "on": true
        },
        "4578964": {
          "on": true,
          "isLocked": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Right now it's not.

Comment: @NickFelker your link doesn't mention anything about this - has it been removed from the documentation?

Comment: Yes report state has been temporarily removed. The API might work but there's no guarantee.

Comment: @NickFelker could we have more informations about that ? Why this is disable ? When this will be back ?

Comment: Hello, I have updated this answer a while back as the documentation has been added back.